# Is creation of an instance of type ArraySlice<Character> via this approach an O(1) time operation?

Tags: swift, unicode, slice, random-access, grapheme-cluster

Re: Swift 5

```
let str = "my string"

let slice: ArraySlice<Character> = ArraySlice(str)
```

Is the `ArraySlice` created in `O(1)` time?

I'm curious because complexities pertaining to extended grapheme clusters exist; such as **emojis** & **diacritics** which are larger than normal ascii characters.

Documentation I've read says array slices can be created at O(1) time, but I've never seen an example shown as the one I present above.

**How could an ArraySlice be created at O(1) time?**

**Wouldn't the string have to first be traversed entirely to know the actual size of each character?**

`ArraySlice` conforms to `RandomAccessProtocol`, and `RandomAccessProtocol` conformity yields the `.count` `O(1)` benefit, which is why I ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, an array slice cannot be created in O(1) in this way. Specifically, array slices can only be created *from an already existing array* in O(1) time; the initializer you are calling on [`ArraySlice` has to create a copy of the sequence you pass in](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d041d4a112ef5c075b48bbb747d8b6e421e88e18/stdlib/public/core/ArraySlice.swift#L679) (O(n)) and creates a slice out of the intermediate array it creates (O(1)):

```swift
@inlinable
public init<S: Sequence>(_ s: S)
  where S.Element == Element {

  self.init(_buffer: s._copyToContiguousArray()._buffer)
}
```

> Wouldn't the string have to first be traversed entirely to know the actual size of each character?

This is exactly correct.

Comment: Worth noting that despite this up-front cost, this is the correct way to go about implementing algorithms with lots of integer subscriptions if strings. You pay the traversal cost once, rather than on each indexing operation

Comment: Depending on what you need to do, it can be even more efficient to copy the string’s _indices_ for use (e.g. `Array(someString.indices)`). You still pay for the O(n) traversal but you have indices with relative offsets that can be used to index into the string in O(1) time, along with the usual benefits of O(1) array access.